# udev doesn't work when usb otg device is attached during boot

Tags: raspberry-pi, udev, usb-otg

I have a setup consisting of a raspberry pi 3 connected to a raspberry pi zero via OTG usb connection.  I have followed the following tutorial exactly: http://raspberryjamberlin.de/zero360-part-2-connecting-via-otg-a-cluster-of-raspberry-pi-zeros-to-a-pi-3/#OTG

In my ‘/etc/udev/rules.d/90-panocluster.rules’ in pi3 I have:

> SUBSYSTEM=="net", ATTR{address}=="00:22:82:ff:ff:01", NAME="ethpi1"

On the zero I have changed the required settings as well.

I am having an issue where if the zero and the pi3 are connect when I power on the pi3, ifconfig will always show usb0 instead of ethpi1.  If I boot up pi3 first and then connect the zero, either usb0 or ethpi1 can show up.  If I reconnected the pi zero's usb (as many times as needed) ethpi1 will show up.

Does anyone know what is causing this annoying issue?

Comment: Did you figure out the solution? I'm also having the same issue.

Comment: @yannis No I disconnected and reconnected until the correct name as a work around.

Answer (score 0):

I used "[contactless/hubpower](https://github.com/contactless/hubpower)" on github to switch off the power to the USB ports and switch them on again. You can follow the instructions found in this [thread here](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=113651#p780287). The renaming of the interfaces works automatically if you followed the tutorial you mention ([here](http://raspberryjamberlin.de/zero360-part-2-connecting-via-otg-a-cluster-of-raspberry-pi-zeros-to-a-pi-3/#OTG)).